# Samba AD + Windows 10 Smart card Login

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, dns, samba, active-directory

I have a Samba4 AD DC running on a VM (Ubuntu server 16.04 64bit on VirtualBox), on a Windows 10 client. Then I try to authenticate users via Windows. I already managed to log in using a smart card on another machine, with Windows 7 using these tutorials mainly:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_Smart_Card_Login

Unfortunatly, this is not working on Windows 10 (I re-did the tutorial entirely on this new machine).

I can log in using users from the Samba domain (Administrator, test_user). But with a smart card, I get a "RPC failure". This is odd, because my VM is on the same machine, I don't see why RPC is involved ? After that, my machine restarts by itself. Events log says "LogonUi.exe" has crashed.

Oddly, my samba log says I successfully logged in the domain with my card ! (PKINIT pre-authentication succeeded, authtime : xxx, just like on my Win7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by updating manually (building from sources) the latest version of Samba (4.7.3).

Using a server LTS version of Ubuntu, I didn't have the latest fixes (it was running ver 4.3.11). I compiled the sources and it works fine now.